# Array with database data

Tags: php

I need to assemble an array by pulling the slug from my table, example:

```
$array = array (
   'esporte',
   'mundo',
   'estado'
);
```

I tried like this:

```
$slug = $con->prepare("SELECT slug FROM categorias");
$slug->execute();
$array = array (
   foreach ( $slug as $row ) {
      echo "'.$row['slug'].',";
   }
);
```

I need to use this array to make a friendly url that looks like this:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
$sep = array_filter ( explode ( "/", $url ) );
if ( isset ( $sep[0] ) && $sep[0] in_array ( $sep[0], $array ) ) {
   $Categoria = new Categoria;
   $Categoria->GetCategoria();
}
```